# What is the syntax for a gradle subproject task depending on a parent project's task?

Tags: gradle, build, dependencies

I need some help with a Gradle build file. I have some subprojects which depend on tasks in the top folder. I just need to take a `test` task and split it into two separate test tasks. Currently the file system structure looks like (tab indicates files inside a directory):

```
top-level-project-folder
    A.gradle
    B.gradle
    C-subproject-folder
        C.gradle
    D-subproject-folder
        D.gradle
```

Contents of A.gradle (before refactor):

```
subprojects {
    tasks.test.dependsOn {
        bTask
    }
}
apply from: 'B.gradle'
```

Contents of C.gradle (before refactor):

```
test {
    ...
}
```

After the refactor, C.gradle needs to look like:

```
test {
    ...
}

task runDifferentTests(type : Test) {
    ...
}
```

The tricky part is that `C.gradle`'s `test` task currently depends on `bTask`. However, after the refactor, `C.gradle`'s `test` task should *not* depend on `bTask`, but the new `runDifferentTests` task should depend on `bTask`. (Currently, `D.gradle`'s `test` task is marked as depending on `bTask`, but it does not actually depend on it -- I'd like to remove that dependency. The only task in the two subprojects which depends on `bTask` is the new `runDifferentTests` task.)

I've tried some different things but can't seem to find a working solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the declaration in `subprojects` and declare your dependency directly in the subproject, in `C.gradle`:

```
runDifferentTests.dependsOn rootProject.bTask
```

Comment: At first I thought you meant `runDifferentTests.dependsOn A.bTask` which gives errors. It took me a minute to realize you meant a literal `rootProject`. This is good to know, thank you so much!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP wants to know how can **the parent project** express that something needs to happen before a subproject task. Your answer inverts the resposibility / awareness of what needs to happen.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the question. On the contrary, the title says "syntax for a gradle SUBproject". Also, it is somewhat bold to claim something does not answer a question after the OP selected it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax solutions here:

```groovy
runDifferentTests.dependsOn (":bTask")

runDifferentTests.dependsOn rootProject.bTask

task runDifferentTests(type : Test, dependsOn: [":bTask"]) {
...
}

task runDifferentTests(type : Test) {
dependsOn rootProject.bTask
...
}

//in the root build.gradle to apply to all subprojects at once.
subprojects {
    runDifferentTests.dependsOn (":bTask")
}

runDifferentTests.dependsOn {
    tasks.findAll { task -> task.name.startsWith('bTask') }
}
```

`:` can be used to go a level up instead of rootProject depends on the preference and the project structure

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (using gradle 8.0.1 at the moment):

For example => if one or more of your subprojects do have a task named "checkDependencies" you could apply this in your root projects gradle:

```groovy
tasks.register('dependencyCheckRoot') {
dependsOn(provider {
    subprojects.tasks.collect({ task -> task.findByName('checkDependencies') }).findAll {it}
})
  doLast {
     ... your task content ...
  }
}
```

If you now call the *dependencyCheckRoot* it will depend on all the subproject tasks found.