# Have all gradle subproject 'test' tasks depend on rootproject 'setup' task

Tags: gradle

I thought this would work but things must have changed(or I have some sort of mistake)

[What is the syntax for a gradle subproject task depending on a parent project's task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666307/what-is-the-syntax-for-a-gradle-subproject-task-depending-on-a-parent-projects)

I have the following task at the root level(ie. outside the subprojects closure and outside the allprojects closure).

```
task deleteJavaCache {
    doLast {
        System.out.println("DELETE java caches here to prevent intermitten build failures from java deleting files")
    }
}

test.dependsOn rootProject.deleteJavaCache
test{
   beforeTest{ descr ->
    logger.warn("Starting Test ${descr.className} : ${descr.name}")
   }
...
```

The error I get is

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'webpieces'.
> Could not get unknown property 'deleteJavaCache' for root project 
'webpieces' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I then guessed a few things including this one

```
test.dependsOn rootProject.task('deleteJavaCache')
```

but that gave me the error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'webpieces'.
> Cannot add task ':deleteJavaCache' as a task with that name already exists.
```

version info is thus

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.1-milestone-1
------------------------------------------------------------
Build time:   2017-06-20 17:05:46 UTC
Revision:     3ad5af92d482b963cc6b00fb5ad53b608606d657

Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
```

Comment: Could you try `rootProject.tasks['deleteJavaCache']`?

Comment: @lu.koerfer close! but it errors out with "Task with name 'deleteJavaCache' not found in root project 'webpieces'." which is weird as I define it as in the post which is how my other new targets are defined.

Comment: oh, since then I tried a global task that I use for releasing called uploadArchives2 and it says that does not exist which is definitely not true as my releasing would break.

Comment: long story short, I am trying to run a target before all tests run AND only run that thing once.  My full build.gradle without adding the code above is here https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/build.gradle  (I am trying to tweak this file)

Comment: Where in your `build.gradle` did you define the `deleteJavaCache` task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your `settings.gradle` and if the subproject is `include` there

---

If  I understand it Right it's like this:

```
root (deleteJavaCache)
  |- subprojects (test.dependsOn deleteJavaCache from the root)
```

Try this:

```
test.dependsOn (":deleteJavaCache")
```

or if you want all subprojects `test` tasks to run it before:

```
//in root build.gradle
subprojects {
    test.dependsOn (":deleteJavaCache")
}
```

**as I presume you are trying to customize the subprojects `test` task to make it depend on the root project's task?**

because it is a bit confusing you stated:

> I have the following task at the root level

which means the whole code block is in the root project, both `deleteJavaCache` and `test` tasks. If yes try the below solution if not, the above one and please clarify the question.

```
test.dependsOn deleteJavaCache
```

Comment: there was a link in the comments to the actual build file https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: hmmm, yes, this one seems to be working.  ie. test.dependsOn (":deleteJavaCache") so it depends on the root project's single deleteJavaCache target.